# Using clj-schema to validate that a sequence of maps has unique values for a given key

Tags: validation, clojure, clj-schema

I have a request object which contains a sequence of maps. I want to validate that there are no duplicate values for a given key in those maps.

For example, this is valid:

```
[
  { :id 1, :data "foo" }
  { :id 2, :data "bar" }
]
```

This is invalid because it contains a duplicate of `:id 1`:

```
[
  { :id 1, :data "foo" }
  { :id 2, :data "bar" }
  { :id 1, :data "baz" }
]
```

Currently I have something similar to:

```
(def-map-schema item-schema
                [[:id] integer?
                 [:data] string?])

(def-map-schema request-schema
                [[:items] (sequence-of item-schema)])
```

How can this uniqueness constraint be expressed using `clj-schema`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clj-schema provides a function, `clj-schema.schema/simple-schema`, that can be used to turn arbitrary predicates into schemas. Here's how to use it to implement a `maps-with-unique-key?` schema:

```
(defn maps-with-unique-key? [k]
  (s/simple-schema [(s/sequence-of map?)
                    (fn [xs]
                      (= (count xs)
                         (count (distinct (map #(get % k) xs)))))]))
```

At the REPL:

```
(v/valid? (maps-with-unique-key? :id)
          [])
;= true
(v/valid? (maps-with-unique-key? :id)
          [{:id 0 :foo "bar"} {:id 1 :foo "baz"} {:id 2 :foo "quux"}])
;= true
(v/valid? (maps-with-unique-key? :id)
          [{:id 0 :foo "bar"} {:id 1 :foo "baz"} {:id 0 :foo "quux"}])
;= false
(v/valid? (maps-with-unique-key? :id)
          [["not a map"] {:id 0 :foo "bar"} {:id 1 :foo "baz"} {:id 2 :foo "quux"}])
;= false
```

---

*(What follows is my original answer for Prismatic schema.)*

I don't think there's a ready-made schema for this in the standard schema distribution, but it's always possible to implement a new one -- see the [Defining New Schema Types](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema/wiki/Defining-New-Schema-Types) page in schema's wiki.

Here's a sketch:

```
(defrecord MapsWithUniqueKey [k]
  s/Schema
  (walker [this]
    (fn [x]
      (if (and (or (seq? x) (vector? x))
               (every? map? x)
               (every? #(contains? % k) x)
               (== (count x)
                   (count (distinct (map #(get % k) x)))))
        x
        (schema.macros/validation-error
         this x
         (list 'maps-with-unique-key? k (schema.utils/value-name x))))))
  (explain [this]
    (list 'maps-with-unique-key? k)))
```

Example validations:

```
(s/check (->MapsWithUniqueKey :id)
         [{:id 1 :foo "bar"} {:id 2 :foo "baz"} {:id 3 :foo "quux"}])
;= nil
(s/check (->MapsWithUniqueKey :id)
         [{:id 1 :foo "bar"} {:id 2 :foo "baz"} {:id 1 :foo "quux"}])
;= (not (maps-with-unique-key? :id a-clojure.lang.PersistentVector))
```

The `nil` returned from the first call indicates success, while the latter return value is a `schema.utils.ValidationError`.

Comment: Thanks, but your code uses Prismatic schema, not clj-schema :) I may take a look at it though, as it seems to be more actively developed.

Comment: Oops, sorry, can't believe I missed that! Guess I've been seeing too much of Prismatic schema lately. :-) It is a great library, well worth taking a look. Anyway, I'll edit my answer to add a solution that works with clj-schema 1.0.0 in a second.